# injquery expand and collapse + php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Hi I am executing mysql query and getting the below result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 131.208.0.0
    [1] => 141.128.0.0
    [2] => 141.129.0.0
    [3] => 155.182.0.0
    [4] => 155.183.0.0
 )
```

Using jquery expand I need to print as show below If I click on + it should expand and show below values. I am displaying unique values in UI +131,+141 and +151. And I need to pass these values to php and get the result when I click.

```
 -131.0.0.0
  -131.208.0.0
-141.0.0.0
  -141.1298.0.0
  -141.129.0.0
+155.182.0.0
```

My code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
    $(".msg_body").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".msg_head").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(600);

<div class="msg_body">
        <?php 
            $octets = $this->Ip;
            foreach($octets as $octet){
                //echo "+".$octet."<br />";
            }

            // Here display unique octet value.
            $octetets = $this->octent1;
            foreach($octetets as $octet){
                echo "+".$octet."<br />";
            }


        ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
 $(".msg_body").hide();
 //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
 $(".msg_head").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(600);

Comment: Ya I tried but not able to pass the unique value and get result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work with some minor changes...
[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcThh/1/).